# Set Viewport initial scale level WP8.1 app

Tags: c#, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to set the contents of webview by some string coming dynamically. I just navigate the webview to string but due to this the contents are shown very small in the phone and not readable. In html file we can set the viewport initial scale level how can I achieve the same effect when navigating to the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `WebView` control has a `InvokeScript` and `InvokeScriptAsync` method.

I like using a `WebBrowser` control which has the same methods.  I can set the scale by invoking some script by doing this (try it for the `WebView` to see if it works out for you).

```
// figure out the ratio you want to reduce by (this will be 50%)
string zoom_js = "document.body.style.zoom=\"50%\";";

try
{
    this.myBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
    this.myBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", zoom_js);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```